# How to get Shader Editor Object Info location relative to parent?

Tags: objects, shader-nodes

In my shader editor I use Object Info location to control the colour of objects which have assigned the same material. But all those objects are children of another object (in my case empty). So if I move my parent object then in Shader Editor Object Info the location is updated by that move, so I end up with unintendent colour changes of all children objects.

So is there any way in Shader Editor to get location which would be relative to the parent object (or any other) instead whole world?